# Can't pull variable from script to patches

Tags: javascript, spark-ar-studio

I'm fairly new to spark-ar and JavaScript and I have problem transfering a variable from my script to the patches, my code consist of a bad mix of things that I've found on the internet.

```
const Patches = require('Patches');
const Scene = require('Scene');

(async function() {
    var scale = {x: 0.5, y: 0.5};
    
await Patches.inputs.setVector('scale', scale);

})();
```

It's not giving me an error but a warning that say: *
Please make sure to define a From script patch with that name and correct type in the patch editor
*
Nothing is happening on the side of the patches and I can't find anything remotely useful.

Comment: Did you create a patch from script? (click on script and in inspector you will see it)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problem with your code -

Patches.inputs.setVector is expecting a [VectorSignal](https://sparkar.facebook.com/ar-studio/learn/reference/classes/ReactiveModule.VectorSignal), and in Spark a VectorSignal is actually three values: XYZ. If you are looking to pass just X and Y values, you should use a [Vec2Signal](https://sparkar.facebook.com/ar-studio/learn/reference/classes/ReactiveModule.Point2DSignal#properties) instead.

In your code, {x: 0.5, y: 0.5} - you are actually making a [Javascript object](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp), not a Vec2Signal.

To create a Vec2Signal, use [Reactive.point2d](https://sparkar.facebook.com/ar-studio/learn/reference/classes/reactivemodule#methods) instead.

The correct code would be:

```
const Patches = require('Patches');
const Scene = require('Scene');
const Reactive = require('Reactive');

(async function() {
    
    var scale = Reactive.point2d(.5, .5);
    await Patches.inputs.setPoint2D('scale', scale);

})();
```